# Custom post type needs to capability to create and edit by some specific user role

Tags: custom-field, user-roles, membership

I made a custom post type called "Jobs" by ACF. I am using "Members" plugin to give users role. I want some users will get the capability to create post and edit post. others capability will be pointed only for admin. How can I achieve this?
Thanks